# Sorteio entre Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Boa tarde, queria saber como faço para escolher um número máximo em uma activity e na outra fazer um sorteio com o número máximo sendo o que foi escolhido na primeira activity

Comment: Não está muito clara a sua pergunta, tente reformula-la e acrescentar mais detalhes. Poste também o código que você já tem e qual é a sua dúvida especificamente.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas o que você deseja provavelmente é passar dados entre *activities*. Para isso, você vai precisar de um [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

Supondo que você tenha gerado um `int` e queira passá-lo entre *activities*:

```
int seuNumero = 10;

Intent intent = new Intent(SUA_ACTIVITY_ATUAL.class, ACTIVITY_DE_DESTINO.class);
intent.putExtra("seuNumero", seuNumero);
startActivity(intent);
```

Na `Activity` de destino, você precisa do código a seguir para recuperar seu número:

```
int numero = getIntent().getIntExtra("seuNumero");
```

Atente-se ao método `getIntExtra()`. Ele é usado para recuperar um valor do tipo `int`. Se você estiver lidando com `double`, vai usar `getDoubleExtra()` etc.